# Error argument list is too long when running Makefile

Tags: makefile, mingw-w64, msys

Error occur on linking to create static library use `ar` with many object files

```
/bin/sh: /mingw64/bin/ar: Argument list too long
```

I am on windows using msys2 when build them. I am tried to copy its command to cmd. The result is error because the command is too long. It didnt work on Rakefile in ruby too with error 127. The question is am i should update the `ar`? Because the problem is in `ar` not `sh`

Comment: Do you own the makefile? Change it dump the command to a temporary file, perhaps? (Then run `ar @commands.txt`.)

Comment: How the command? Its error `invalid option -- @`

Comment: It works on my end. `ar --version` is 2.41. I'm running it on Linux with Wine, but it should make no difference. Did you accidentally add space after `@`?

Comment: Now its work. My ar need more args. Thanks